# OpenXml: Programmatically get NumberingRestart settings for Footnotes

Tags: c#, openxml

Footnotes have numbering restart options. Numbering can be restarted from: page, section or can be continuous.

How can I programmatically get numbering restart setting(s) for footnotes of an existing docx document.

Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document wide footnote settings can be found in the `DocumentSettingsPart`.
The releated class in the OpenXml SDK is called `FootnoteDocumentWideProperties`.

The sample below reads the footnote numbering restart settings configured by the user:

```
public static void ReadFootnoteNumberingRestartSettings()
{
  using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = 
         WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\temp\Doc1.docx", true)) 
  {
    FootnoteDocumentWideProperties fdwp = 
             wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.Elements<FootnoteDocumentWideProperties>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (fdwp == null)
    {
      Console.Out.WriteLine("No document wide footnote settings specified.");
      return;
    }

    if (fdwp.NumberingRestart == null)
    {
      Console.Out.WriteLine("No numbering restart settings specified.");
      return;
    }

    Console.Out.WriteLine("Numbering restart option: {0}", fdwp.NumberingRestart.Val);    
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ReadFootnoteNumberingRestartSettings();
}
```